# @DbLookup in Notes Client?

Tags: xpages

I have a computed field with the following formula:

@DbLookup("","vwFormTypesByFormTypeOrder","EXTCAB006","ReasonType");

It works fine in Domino Xpages but does not work in the Notes Client Xpages.

To get it to work in Notes Client Xpages, I need to specify the server and database name.

This is not how @Dblookup works in Notes forms.

Is this a bug in Xpages?  Or at the very least a poorly documented function?

Answer (score 5):

Works as designed. @JS is only similar to @Formula and you need to specify the database in @JS. Simply use @DbName. That it works without @DbName in Domino is nice but undocumented (AFAIK). See also: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_DbColumn_and_DbLookup